# How to call the function by onClick the button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = DataAccess.getWithdrawList();

            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            html.Append("<div class='row mt'>");
            html.Append("<div class='col-md-12'>");
            html.Append("<div class='content-panel'>");
            html.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>");
            html.Append("<h4><i class='fa'></i>Withdrawal List</h4>");
            html.Append("<hr>");
            html.Append("<thead>");
            html.Append("<tr>");

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th><i class='fa'></i>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }

            html.Append("</tr>");
            html.Append("</thead>");
            html.Append("<tbody>");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td runat='server'>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("<td><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button></td>");
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            html.Append("</tbody>");
            html.Append("</table>");
            html.Append("</div>");
            html.Append("</div>");
            html.Append("</div>");

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I want to onclick button to call the btnSubmit function and retrieve data from every single row of the data column from HTML Table into backend code but I failed to do so because I couldn't call the function by the button click in asp.net, anyone have ideas of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: Your shouldn't generate your HTML by using just a Literal; you need to create your table and buttons directly as ASPNET controls in your aspx page. Have a look at [how to create a basic ASPNET WebForm page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page)

Comment: The reason I do in this way because I want the table design layout, is there any way to do it?

Comment: @AlexanderYap Yes, there are asp.net web server controls for table design, see MSDN article: [Table, TableRow, and TableCell Web Server Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0ce8sc.aspx)